# PHP: How to strip HTML tag while allowing < and >

Tags: php, html

**Question:** How do I strip HTML tags but allow the greater and less-than sign using PHP?

If I used PHP's `strip_tags()` function, it doesn't quite work:

```
$string = '<p>if A > B</p>'
echo strip_tags($string);  // if A B
// but I want to output "if A > B"
```

**UPDATE**

Basically, I only want to allow/display plain text.

Comment: You know you shouldn't have < and > in HTML anyway? You should use character entities instead such as &lt; and &gt; - the browser will render them as < and >

Comment: DrJokepu is correct. Your snippet is invalid HTML.

Comment: @DrJokepu, so if I use htmlspecialchars(), that encodes the > to &gt; but doesn't strip tags. Basically, I only want to allow plain-text. What's the simplest way to do that?

Comment: @SpliFF - no it isn't invalid. Add a doctype and a title element, and try it via the direct input box at http://validator.w3.org/check.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996344/is-preventing-xss-and-sql-injection-as-easy-as-does-this IMHO just leave `strip_tags()` aside and go ahead with `htmlspecialchars()`. No need to exagerrate this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) this will not only work with the `<p>if A > B</p>` example which you wrote, but also the example `<p>1<2 && 6>4</p>` written by [DrJokepu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8954/drjokepu).

Given the input `<p>1<2 && 6>4</p>` with the allowed elements set to none, HTML purifier gives the output: `1&lt;2 &amp;&amp; 6&gt;4`.

Answer (score 0):

This will strip everything that looks like an HTML tag.

```
htmlentities(preg_replace('/<\\S.*?>/', '', $text));
```

Comment: This will fail on <p>1<2 && 6>4</p> - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the simplest and most reliable way to get this working is to use an HTML parser. [This one](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) will do the trick. I don't know if it'll handle HTML fragments like the above. If not, then wrapping to make it acceptable HTML should be trivial.

As others are pointing out, parsing HTML with a regexp has numerous edge cases to cater for, and difficulty, since HTML is not regular.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression that I wrote: <([^>]*?="(\"|[^"])*?")*?([^>]*?=''(\''|[^''])*?'')*?[^>]*?>

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars("if A > B") ?></p>
```

(of course you can use any input instead of literal string)

`htmlspecialchars()` converts plain text to HTML text, preserving `<` and `>`.

Comment: It doesn't strip HTML tags, as the OP asked.