# Escaping data - stripslashes, strip_tags

Tags: php, html, escaping

Why do a lot of people use both these functions on a string?
I see a lot of `stripslashes(strip_tags($field));` (or the other way around)

Isn't `strip_tags` enough to filter any xss stuff and such things?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Escaping data has nothing to do with `strip_tags` or `stripslashes`. These functions filter certain characters out of a string while "escaping" encodes certain characters so they won't be interpreted by a browser or database.

You can use `strip_tags` to remove HTML tags in strings being sent to PHP from the browser. Better yet, you could also safely store the same data without passing it through `strip_tags` if you use `htmlspecialchars` to escape any characters that could delimit tags when you send the data back to the browser.

[`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) removes slashes from a string, and you only need to worry about it if "magic quotes" are enabled. It's a hold-over from an earlier time when the PHP devs naively assumed every piece of data coming from the browser was destined for a database and that developers couldn't be trusted to escape the database themselves.

Answer (score 5):

> Isn't strip_tags enough to filter any xss stuff and such things?

Nope. The only safe way to filter out XSS stuff is `htmlspecialchars()`, although I see many recommendations to use `strip_tags()` in addition.

See e.g. discussion in this question: [Is preventing XSS and SQL Injection as easy as does this…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996344/is-preventing-xss-and-sql-injection-as-easy-as-does-this)

What the `stripslashes` is supposed to do in this context, I have no idea. It is probably an attempt to undo the effects of the now-deprecated [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) function - but this should never be applied without checking first whether that particular function is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

When magic quotes is on it will automatically escape quotes in all of the POST, GET, etc. variables.  stripslashes removes those before you use the data.  Strip tags *tries* to remove all of the html tags.

Answer (score 1):

`strip_tags()` usually isn't enough to prevent XSS attacks on it's own, so it's best to err on the side of caution.

Consider the following:

```
$str = "' onclick='javascript:alert(0);' alt='";
echo "<a href='". strip_tags($str) ."'></a>";
// output is <a href='' onclick='javascript:alert(0);' alt=''></a>
```

One doesn't always need HTML tags to execute an XSS attack.  It may be a less effective attack, but it's still a potential attack vector nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that strip_tags() adds backslashes to quote characters. I have checked and magic_quotes_gpc is NOT turned on. The OP's original question was why some coders surround strip_tags() with stripslashes() and that is why I do it, because I don't want the database to store double backslashes since I already prepare my data anyway before saving it to the database.