# Having weird trouble using a PHP post function

Tags: php, mysql, post, sanitize

So, I've got some pretty basic code that I can't get to work quite right. I'm using the ezSQL class (http://justinvincent.com/ezsql), but that's working fine. Everything works fine, except when I try to use a sanitize function (get_post). I'm using two other functions, sanitizeString and sanitizeMySQL when I call the function get_post. If I just $_POST the data right to the SQL table, it works fine. It's only when I go thru the post function that it breaks. Here's the posting bit:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) &&
isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = get_post('username');
    $password = get_post('password');
    $db->query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$username', '$password')");
}
```

Like I said, I'm using a class (that's what the $db->query stuff is about), but that's working perfectly. If I change the code to this:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) &&
isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $db->query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$username', '$password')");
}
```

it works fine.  Here are the three functions I'm using for sanitizing:

```
 // Sanitize Functions
function sanitizeString($var)
{
 if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $var = stripslashes($var);
 $var = htmlentities($var);
 $var = strip_tags($var);
 return $var;
}    

function sanitizeMySQL($var)
{
 $var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);
 $var = sanitizeString($var);
 return $var;
}    

function get_post($var) 
{
return sanitizeMySQL($_POST['$var']);
}
```

I've even tried just changing the get_post function to contain a mysql_real_escape_string return, and even that doesn't work. Also, I guess I should clarify what actually happens when I try to use the get_post function. It appears to create a new row in the table, but with completely empty cells. Hope you guys can shed some light on what I'm doing wrong! I'm a pretty experienced front-end developer, but I'm kinda learning the ropes with server-side stuff. Thanks :)

ninjaEdit: I found this question [Are these two functions overkill for sanitization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940030/are-these-two-functions-overkill-for-sanitization) which is definitely helpful in making my sanitize functions better, but it doesn't really help me with why mine aren't working in the first place.

Comment: sanitizeMySQL should be `if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $var = stripslashes($var);` __then__ `$var=mysql_real_escape_string($var);` only. Your messing with the mysql encoded string, so its no longer escaped correctly

Comment: have you considered using pdo and prepared statements? If you use this engine you don't need to care about escaping when you bind param PDO does it for you.

Comment: I started using PDO and prepared statements. Thanks for the suggestion! Still not sure if I need to sanitize more than just using bind params though

Answer (score 1):

why did you put ' around `$var` ?

in the function get_post you should do `return sanitizeMySQL($_POST[$var]);`

you should use prepared statement so it escapes character for you

Comment: Thanks :) I'm using a prepared statement now

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` should be the last thing you do, to make the string ready for database use.
Playing around with the escaped string AFTER mysql_real_escape_string could render the string useless for queries

```
// Sanitize Functions
function sanitizeString($var)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    return $var;
}    

function sanitizeMySQL($var)
{
    $var = sanitizeString($var);
    $var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);
    return $var;
}    

function get_post($var) 
{
    return sanitizeMySQL($_POST[$var]);
}
```

p.s.
get_post() would be better written if you pass the variable rather than the name of the post index.

ie

```
function get_var($var) 
{
    return sanitizeMySQL($var);
}

get_var($_POST['message']); 
get_var($_POST['message'][0]); // array elements on the form 
get_var($_GET['index']);  // GET parameter
get_var($_FILES['file']['name']);  // original name of uploaded file
```